# Rerendering does not work properly in react-bootstrap tabs

Tags: reactjs, tabs, renderer, react-bootstrap

In case of the showSecondTab value changed the defaultActiveKey value changes and the second tab appears and disappears but the active tab does not change.
If the whol block is rerendered it works properly.
There should be problem with rerendering of tabs.

```
<Tabs
    unmountOnExit={true}
    defaultActiveKey={showSecondTab ? 2 : 1}
    id="allTabs">
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="First tab">
    <FirstTabContent />
    </Tab>
    {showSecondTab &&
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="Second tab">
            <SecondTabContent />
        </Tab>
    }
</Tabs>
```

There is no change if the code is the next.

```
createTabs() {
    if(showSecondTab) {
        return (
            <Tabs
                unmountOnExit={true}
                defaultActiveKey={2}
                id="allTabs">
                <Tab eventKey={1} title="First tab">
                    <FirstTabContent />
                </Tab>
                <Tab eventKey={2} title=""Second tab">
                    <SecondTabContent />
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        )
    } else {
       return (
            <Tabs
                unmountOnExit={true}
                defaultActiveKey={1}
                id="allTabs">
                <Tab eventKey={1} title="First tab">
                    <FirstTabContent />
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        )
    }
}

render(){
    {this.createTabs()}
}
```